# When I disable MouseLook in Unity, I can still look up and down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I made a pop up menu and when it comes up, I don't want to be able to move or look around. The movement part is all good, but when I disable MouseLook, I can still look up and down. How can I fix this? Also, I don't want to freeze the game time because I might add multiplayer later and I don't want it to freeze the game for other players. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
if(canOpen == true && isOpen == false && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
        isOpen = true;
        canClose = true;
        player.GetComponent<FPSInputController>().enabled = false;
        player.GetComponent<CharacterMotor>().enabled = false;
        player.GetComponent<MouseLook>().enabled = false;
    }
    else if(isOpen == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && canClose == true) {
        isOpen = false;
        canOpen = false;
        player.GetComponent<FPSInputController>().enabled = true;
        player.GetComponent<CharacterMotor>().enabled = true;
        player.GetComponent<MouseLook>().enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `MouseLook` components on Unity's standard `First Person Controller`: one on the player root that handles rotation about the y-axis (`MouseX`), and another on the `Camera` for the x-axis (`MouseY`).

To enable/disable both, you could use:

```
foreach(var mouseLook in player.GetComponentsInChildren<MouseLook>())
    mouseLook.enabled = false;
```